# Angular Subscribe and Bind to emitted event

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a method in my component that is triggered when a dropdown value is changed. This triggers a modal component to popup and prompt for a note regarding the change that was just made.

I am subscribing to an emitted event from the modal and passing it to another method so that when the note is filled out and button is clicked, it passes that note to another method where I processes it and store it.

```
/**
 * On the update of a task status
 * @param $event
 * @param task 
 */
onTaskStatusChange($event, task) {

    // Define our status/task
    let taskID = task.elementRef.nativeElement.dataset.taskid;
    let statusID = $event.StatusID;

    // Call our modal, pass the ConfirmRemoveRuleModalComponent
    this._bsModalRef = this._modalService.show(TransitionPromptComponent);
    this._bsModalRef.content.action.take(1).subscribe(this.doTaskStatusChange.bind(this, taskID, statusID));
}

/**
 * After entering our note on the transition prompt, update the status
 * @param note 
 * @param taskID 
 * @param statusID 
 */
doTaskStatusChange(note, taskID, statusID) {
    console.log(note, taskID, statusID)
}
```

In this code, the `onTaskStatusChange` is what triggers the modal. It then binds the value that will be omitted from it to a new method `doTaskStatusChange`.

This works perfectly fine when I am just passing a single value such as `this._bsModalRef.content.action.take(1).subscribe(this.doTaskStatusChange.bind(this));`

The problem is happening when I am trying to pass some additional values to the second method, along with the value emitted from the component (the note).

In this case, `statusID` in `doTaskStatusChange` is displaying the value of what was emitted from the modal component instead of the numeric value that should have been passed along with it.

Is there a scope issue here where `this` is conflicting with `$event` in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `bind` becomes `this` in the body of the function. You can retrieve the parameters passed to `bind`:

```
this.doTaskStatusChange.bind(this, taskID, statusID)
```

if you define `doTaksStatusChange` as:

```
doTaskStatusChange(taskID, statusID) {
    console.log(this, taskID, statusID)
}
```

You can find an example of the code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-7grnnb).

---

An alternative is to use an arrow function as the callback:

```
this._bsModalRef.content.action.take(1).subscribe((note) => {
    this.doTaskStatusChange(note, taskID, statusID);
});
```

with

```
doTaskStatusChange(note, taskID, statusID) {
    console.log(note, taskID, statusID)
}
```

Comment: So I tried this, and maybe I am doing it wrong but when I logged the data as suggested, it provided the scope of the whole component for `this` instead of just the value that was being emitted from the modal component. Do I need to access it in the scope directly with this approach? Normally, `this` just provides whatever is being emitted from my modal `this.action.emit(this.form.value);`.I am able to access it directly like so `console.log(this._bsModalRef.content.form.value.note, taskID, statusID)`. This satisfies what I need, was more so wondering about why the scope of `this` changed.